# How to set start y-position of ion-content scroll?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, scroll-position, ion-content

I'm trying to set up the scroll position of `ion-content` a little bit down to hide some elements at the beginning of this control.

I need something [like this](https://codepen.io/mhartington/pen/LFszo)

I have tried 'start-y="xx"' attribute but it doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

```
<ion-content start-y="55">
```

Comment: are you using ionic 4 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ionic4 there currently isn't an attribute for scroll starting position. However, there is a scroll method you can use on page initialisation which you can use like so:

.ts

```
    import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
    import {IonContent} from '@ionic/angular';
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-home',
      templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
      styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
    })
    export class HomePage {
         @ViewChild(IonContent) theContent: IonContent;


    ngOnInit() {this.theContent.scrollToPoint(0,150).then(()=>{}) }
    }
}
```

comment if you need anything clarifying

Comment: I just replace 'IonContent' for 'Content' and the method this.theContent.scrollTo(0,150).then(()=>{}) and it works for me! Thank you sr.